# calculate average grade which accept string

Tags: python-3.x, function, parameters, average

In python how to get the average, which accepts as a string input parameter and returns the average of the four scores within the string as a float.

Expected output:

```
input output
0, 50.4, 80.3, 95.9 = 56.5
99.9, 91.3, 99.2, 98.0 = 97.1
```

My output right now is

```
input output
0, 50.4, 80.3, 95.9 = 0
99.9, 91.3, 99.2, 98.0 = 99.9
```

please help me to get the expected output

```
grade1 = 0,50.4,80.3,95.9 
grade2 = 99.9,91.3,99.2,98.0 
gradeArr = [grade1, grade2] 

def score_average (i):
    n = len (i)
    total = 0
    for j in i:
        total = total + j
        average = total 
    return float (average)

print("input output")
for i in gradeArr:
    average = score_averages(i)
    length= len(str(i))
    print(str(i)[1:length -1] + " = " + str(average))
```

Comment: In your `score_average` function, do: `return float(average)/n`. Now you'll get the expected output.

Comment: @Tharsalys it didn't work. but thank you

Comment: It's giving me `56.65` for `grade1` and `97.1` for `grade2`. Please check if it's not some other issue on your end.

Answer (score 0):

The output is `0` and `99.9` because you are returning the first number in the list in the `score_average` function, since the return statement is indented into the for loop, so only the first number is added to the total and then is returned. Also, if you indent it correctly, the return statement is just returning the sum of the list, so you need to return this sum divided by `n` to get the average. The code should look like this:

```
grade1 = 0,50.4,80.3,95.9
grade2 = 99.9,91.3,99.2,98.0 
gradeArr = [grade1, grade2] 

def score_average (i):
    n = len (i)
    total = 0
    for j in i:
        total = total + j
    average = total / n  # Divide the total by n
    return average 

print("input output")
for i in gradeArr:
    average = score_average(i)
    length= len(str(i))
    print(str(i)[1:length -1] + " = " + str(average))
```